# Doctrine lazy-loading batches

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

We have an ORM concept that we are thinking of doing over Doctrine. In our ORM concept, we have a notion  that's called "Aspects" (nothing to do with AOP); "Aspects" are associated to entities and an Aspect contains properties and relations that, in the context of lazy-loading, should be loaded in a batch (i.e. in a single query). For instance, a `User` can have a `listing` context that fetches `{name,picture}`, and it can have a `activity` context that fetches the `{lastLogin,lastPost:listing}` (`listing` here being an Aspect of a Post).

The idea would be that by using Aspects, one would leverage the benefits of lazy loading while at the same time avoiding the one-query-per-field performance pitfall. Whenever an accessor would access an entity or entity list, it would assign one or more Aspects to that access, so that properties and relations that would be eventually used later would be loaded in a single batch.

We are not very familiar with Doctrine though, so my question: is there something similar already in Doctrine or that could be painlessly hooked into the lazy loading mechanism of Doctrine?

Comment: I don't know Doctrine well enough to give a great answer, so I'll instead point to some docs. See [partial objects](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/partial-objects.html) warnings. Perhaps what you want is a custom [Metadata driver](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/metadata-drivers.html#metadata-drivers) and/or a [second level cache](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/second-level-cache.html#the-second-level-cache) strategy. Custom repositories and Redis stores might work, too.

Comment: Aye... so any insight on why relations lazy-loading is supposed to work but not properties? I thought the whole purpose and benefit of the Doctrine proxy classes was to enable the lazy loading. I was under the impression that lazy loading will work as long as properties are accessed by getters (`getField()` instead of `->field`).

Comment: I don't know. Maybe lazy loading is advantageous here only because of the object graph penalty.